# Computing coefficients of $E_4^n$

Tags: number-theory, modular-forms, computational-number-theory

This is a question about computing coefficients of modular forms, in particular about $E_4^4$, or $E_4^n$. Just a disclaimer, I am quite a beginner in this subject, and I am still slowly learning about modular forms of level $> 1$ and with non-trivial characters, so hopefully the answers will try to stick to level $1$ modular forms :)

To be exact, I want to compute $[q^k]E_4^n$, where the factorisation of $k$ is known and quite smooth. Therefore, I want to decompose the expressions into sum of those that have multiplicative coefficients, such as $\Delta$ (where $\tau(n)$ is multiplicative) or $E_k$ (where $\sigma_{k - 1}(n)$ is multiplicative), from which I can compute them in $\tilde{O}\left(\min_{p \mid n} p\right)$ (or $\log$ of that according to literature). Here is my attempt.

For the first expression, I know that $E_4^2 = E_8$, so the coefficients will equal the convoluting sum $[q^n](E_4^4) = [q^n]E_8^2 = \sum_{k = 1}^{n - 1} \sigma_7(k) \sigma_7(n - k)$. However, $E_8^2 \in \mathcal{M}_{16}$ which is two dimensional, so we can't just write $E_8^2 = cE_{16}$. Instead, we have $E_8^2 = \frac{1}{1911}\left(5258E_{16} - 3617E_4E_{12}\right)$, or other equivalent expressions in any basis of $\mathcal{M}_{16}$. Of course, we run into the same problem, as the coefficients of $E_4E_{12}$ is not multiplicative.

From what I know, *eigenforms* should be what I am looking for, since they are eigenvectors of the Hecke operators, and such coefficients are multiplicative. Therefore, I can first find an eigenbasis of $\mathcal{M}_{16}$, which is $\{\Delta E_4, E_{16}\}$, then write $E_4^4$ as a linear combination of them, getting $E_4^4 = \frac{3456000}{3617}\Delta E_4 + E_{16}$. Since $E_4 \Delta$ is an eigenform, by theory of Hecke operators, (1) coefficients are multiplicative and (2) we have $T_{p^{e + 2}} = T_pT_{p^{e + 1}} - p^{16 - 1}T_{p^e}$. This is verified by the following Sage script:

```
sage: M = ModularFormsRing(1)
sage: E4 = M(ModularForms(1, 4).0)
sage: Delta = M(CuspForms(1, 12).0)
sage: coefs = list((E4 * Delta).qexp(101))

sage: for i in range(1, 101):
....:     for j in range(1, 101):
....:         if i * j >= 100: break
....:         if gcd(i, j) > 1: break
....:         assert coefs[i] * coefs[j] == coefs[i * j], f"{i} {j}"

....: for p in prime_range(2, 100):
....:     for e in range(2, floor(log(100, p)) + 1):
....:         assert coefs[p^e] == coefs[p] * coefs[p^(e - 1)] - p^15 * coefs[p^(e - 2)]
```

However, this already took quite some work, and often times the eigenbasis is not as simple. For example, (if I am not mistaken) the eigenbasis of $\mathcal{M}_{24}$ is given by $\{E_{24}, \Delta E_{12} \pm \left(540 \pm 12\sqrt{144169}\right)\Delta^2\}$, which is slightly annoying to deal with. Moreover, even after I obtain such an eigenbasis of $\mathcal{M}_{4n}$ (which is a degree $8$ number field when $n = 25$) I still have to write $E_4^n$ as a linear combination of them, then also compute the first coefficients of them (over the number field), and finally combine them.

Another direction I thought about would be some kind of recursive representation. However, I am not aware of any such ideas, e.g. can I represent the eigenbasis of $\mathcal{M}_{4k + 12}$ in terms of that of $\mathcal{M}_{4k}$? It seems quite difficult, at least numerically I don't see any relation between the following polynomials (the modulus of the number field):

\begin{align*}
P_{12}(x) &= x\\
P_{24}(x) &= x^2 - 1080x - 20468736 \\
P_{36}(x) &= x^3 - 139656x^2 - 59208339456x - 1467625047588864 \\
P_{48}(x) &= x^4 - 5785560x^3 - 467142374034432x^2 + 1426830562183253852160x + 3297913828840214320807673856
\end{align*}

(These are the number fields that the coefficients of the new forms live in, I am not sure if that is what I want here...)

Hence, my question is, is there a simpler way that I am missing?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: @Somos Huh, the coefficients *are* multiplicative, i.e. $a_f(m)a_f(n) = a_f(mn)$ when $(m, n) = 1$. $\Delta E_4$ is an eigenform, so from some basic Hecke operators fact, we have $a_f(p^e) = a_f(p)a_f(p^{e - 1}) - p^{15}a_f(p^{e - 2})$, where $15 = 16 - 1 = w(f) - 1$. I have added this to the post.

Comment: Oops! retracted.

Comment: @Somos Hehe, yeah writing the form in terms of basis of newforms and eisenstein series is the only idea I have, but the representation complexity blows up immediately.

Comment: It is still a good idea, but needs some improvement.

Comment: Let’s assume Maeda’s Conjecture and that $k>>n$. Then it’s easy to write (for the right normalization for $E_t$) $E_4^n=E_{4n}+f$, where $f \in \mathcal{S}_{4n}$ has rational coefficients. By Maeda’s Conjecture, there is a unique cuspidal normalized eigenform $g \in \mathcal{S}_{4n}$ (up to Galois conjugacy), and $f=Tr(cg)$ for some constant $c$. By computing the first $\Theta(n)$ coefficients of $f,g$, you should be able to find out what $c$ is, and then you can use the factorization of $k$ to compute the $q^k$ coefficients of $E_{4n}$ and $g$, hence that of $E_4^n$.

Comment: @Aphelli Thanks a lot, I have written it up and got some code working, which I always find nice :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Aphelli for the hint / answer! I will elaborate a bit here (for my own reference):

I was actually pretty close to the solution at the end, the problem was how to polish the idea of "writing as linear combination of eigenforms". For any cuspidal space $S_{2k}$, by Maeda's conjecture there exists a cusp form $g(q) \in S_{2k}$ such that $S_{2k}$ is spanned by $\{g(q), g^{\sigma}(q), \cdots, g^{\sigma^{d - 1}}(q)\}$, where $d = \dim S_{2k}$ and $\sigma$ is Galois conjugation. In Sage, this is obtained as:

```
sage: nfs = Newforms(1, 48, names="t")
sage: assert len(nfs) == 1
sage: nf = nfs[0]
sage: nf
q + t0*q^2 + (1/7115931648*t0^3 - 120745/296497152*t0^2 - 6878487805/110304*t0 + 458961863849380/8043)*q^3 + (t0^2 - 140737488355328)*q^4 + (593/21962752*t0^3 - 478358379/2745344*t0^2 - 36521357960821/3064*t0 + 65616225923827326366/2681)*q^5 + O(q^6)
sage: nf.base_ring()
Number Field in t0 with defining polynomial x^4 - 5785560*x^3 - 467142374034432*x^2 + 1426830562183253852160*x + 3297913828840214320807673856
```

The key is then to note that if say $E_4^{12} - E_{48} = c_1 g + c_2 g^{\sigma} + c_3 g^{\sigma^2} + c_4 g^{\sigma^4} \in \mathbb{Q}[q]$, then by replacing $c_2, c_3, c_4$ with their appropriate conjugation we get

$$
E_4^{12} - E_{48} = c_1g + (c_2g)^{\sigma} + (c_3g)^{\sigma^2} + (c_4g)^{\sigma^3}
$$

Since the left coefficients are all rational, if we apply $\sigma^k$ to both sides we get

\begin{align*}
\underbrace{\sigma(E_4^{12} - E_{48})}_{\text{fixed}} &= (c_1g)^{\sigma} + (c_2g)^{\sigma^2} + (c_3g)^{\sigma^3} + (c_4g) \\
\sigma^2(E_4^{12} - E_{48}) &= (c_1g)^{\sigma^2} + (c_2g)^{\sigma^3} + (c_3g) + (c_4g)^{\sigma} \\
\sigma^3(E_4^{12} - E_{48}) &= (c_1g)^{\sigma^3} + (c_2g) + (c_3g)^{\sigma} + (c_4g)^{\sigma^2} \\
\end{align*}

Adding up the columns just gives $4(E_4^{12} - E_{48}) = \mathrm{Tr}(c_1g + c_2g + c_3g + c_4g)$, i.e. $E_4^{12} - E_{48} = \mathrm{Tr}(cg)$

This is elementary Galois theory but it went over my head for a second :)

Hopefully this code is useful for someone in the future!

```
sage: # Target
....: f = E4^12 - E48
....: # Eigenform "generator"
....: nf = Newforms(1, 48, names="t")[0]
....: # Number field
....: K = nf.base_ring()
....: t = K.gen()
....: 
....: # We can write f = Tr(c * nf) = sum(c_i * Tr(t^i * nf)), where c_i \in QQ
....: nf_coefs = list(nf.qexp(20))
....: nf_traces = Matrix(QQ, [[(t^i * nc).trace() for nc in nf_coefs] for i in range(K.degree())])
....: # Solve for c_i!
....: f_coefs = list(f.qexp(20))
....: ci = nf_traces.transpose().solve_right(vector(f_coefs))
....: 
....: # Post-processing
....: fc = sum(c * t^i for i, c in enumerate(ci))
....: c50 = (fc * nf.qexp(60)[50]).trace()
....: assert f.qexp(60)[50] == c50
....: print(c50)
-44803420204844408661824671571599103885710728667822338321131164800000000/5609403368997817686249127547
```